# .NET Core Console app - how to display oAuth2 login url to grant permission?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, asp.net-core-1.0, .net-core-rc2

I have a .NET Core console app that is trying to call a protected REST service that requires oAuth2 authentication. **The console app correctly POSTs to auth endpoint and receives 200 OK status with HTML response**. Problem is how do I display this to user so that he can go ahead and log in and grant permission to the console app, so that the app can move along with next steps (obtain access token and apply it to the protected service)?

```
            var response = await Utility.HttpClient.PostAsync(
            _gmaTokenInfo["AuthHost"].ToString(),
            _gmaTokenInfo["AuthEndPoint"].ToString(),
            () => {
                var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                dictionary.Add("access_type", "offline");
                dictionary.Add("response_type", "code");
                dictionary.Add("client_id", _gmaTokenInfo["ClientId"].ToString());
                dictionary.Add("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:55413/authorize/");
                dictionary.Add("scope", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send https://mail.google.com/");
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dictionary);
                return content;
            },
            new System.Threading.CancellationToken()
            ).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // expect html response
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

In the above code, **responseContent** is a valid HTML. If this app was based on .NET Framework, I could launch a browser using System.Diagnostics.Process class which is not supported in .NET Core. 
I suppose this app could well have been a ASP.NET core (previously known as ASP.NET 5) app and I would still run into the same problem.
Anybody who has worked with latest .NET core and oAUth2 lately might have some clues but anyone with some insights, please respond :)

Comment: [`Process`](https://dotnet.github.io/api/System.Diagnostics.Process.html) is supported in .Net Core.

Comment: @svick thanks. I forgot to install "System.Diagnostics.Process" package! I'm all set.

Comment: Any reason  you aren't using the Google .net client library instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Also as far as google auth goes you are using a console application which is a native app which doesn't need a redirect uri

Comment: @DalmTo, good questions. (1) my reason for not using Google client library is that my app is based on .NET core only. Google client library, as I understand it, only supports on .NET framework at the moment. (2) The Google API I'm after is Gmail which only supports 3LO oAuth i.e. requires user consent page and redirect uri. I'm using "localhost" for redirect uri.